# PHP - how to output a MySQL average store rating in a loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with ratings for every store in a directory. I want to display the average rating from each store on a business directory list page. I have the directory business listing page finished without the average rating.

I believe I have figured out how to create an average rating, but I don't know how to get the rating to output in the loop for each store.

Here is how I calculate the rating:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(rating) FROM reviews GROUP BY store_id WHERE store_id = '$storeid'");
$rating_for_page = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$rating = $rating_for_page[0];
```

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to output store details along with its average rating? Did you try a `JOIN` with the store table?

Comment: @sjagr Ya its the same script you helped me with last night.

Comment: Go with @Barmar's query. If you're trying to provide store names at the same time, use `JOIN stores ON stores.store_id = reviews.store_id` after your `FROM reviews` and add `stores.*` to the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: If possible, you should use mysqli instead of mysql (deprecated).

Comment: @sjagr thanks I need to do some more tutorials :)

Comment: @Loopo I think you said that last night on one of my other questions, how come you say that? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: @MichaelFalciglia MySQLi has many advantages, like an object-oriented interface, **prepared statements** (where you define a query and data types, which will be sanitized before querying and thus avoiding **SQL injection** attacks), support for multiple statements at once, etc. But that's a different question, do some research first. It's fine (but I wouldn't recommend it) for you to **learn** using simple MySQL functions, always looking for a switch to MySQLi in a production environment.

Comment: @AlejandroIván Thanks it sounds interesting, I will look into it in the future after I learn the basics a little better

Comment: With all due respect, learning anything about `mysql_query` is damaging. Learn prepared statements. Period. They are the only reasonable way to do this thing and maintain a layer of separation between query and data. Using one of `mysqli` or PDO is essential, it **is** the basics.

Comment: @tadman true, but I believe he's trying to learn **MySQL**, which would be a pain combined with **mysqli**

Comment: There's nothing painful about `mysqli`. Please stop being overly dramatic. Learning placeholders takes **literally** ten minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the query:

```
echo "<table>\n";
echo "<tr><th>Store ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Avg. Rating</th></tr>\n";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT s.store_id, s.store_name, AVG(r.rating) AS avg_rating
                       FROM stores as s
                       JOIN ratings as r ON s.store_id = r.store_id
                       GROUP BY s.store_id");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>$row[store_id]</td><td>$row[store_name]</td><td>$row[avg_rating]</td></tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

Then loop through the results of this query. Each row will be the average rating of a different store.

Comment: He wants to display the average on every store (I assume the specific one for that store), so his code wouldn't be that bad, supposing he'll only show one average (the actual one for the particular store).

Comment: Does it matter that I am pulling the reviews from 1 table and the store data is from another table?

Comment: It's really hard to give precise advice without seeing more context. If you have another query that's returning more details about each store, you should be able to join it with this query to get the details and the rating at the same time.

Comment: if you don't know what a join is, you need to learn, as they're necessary for any but the simplest use of SQL. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for learning how to program, we're not a tutoring service.

Comment: @MichaelFalciglia no, that's what `JOIN` exists for. Just make sure you store one common identifier in every table to make the `SELECT` correctly. For example, having tables `Stores` and `Ratings`, you could do something like `SELECT s.store_id AS store_id, AVG(r.rating) AS avg_rating FROM Stores AS s, Ratings AS r WHERE s.store_id='{$storeid}' AND s.store_id = r.store_id` (that's a manual join, just to clarify what is happening "under the hood").

Comment: Ya I agree Barmar, I have been doing php tutorials everyday, I need to learn MySQL better

Comment: I've modified the query to show how you can combine information from the `stores` and `rating` tables with a simple JOIN. My example outputs everything in a table, but you can get more elaborate with your HTML.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I am going to try it now!

Comment: Barmar after looking it over, if I understand your code correctly, it will print out a table with the store name, the store id and the average rating each in their own table cell on a row. What I don't understand is how does the loop identify which store rating to print at that place in the loop.

Comment: Oh `$row` is it, sorry missed that

Comment: The `JOIN` links the two tables based on `store_id`. So all the data in each row is for a specific store.

Comment: Does `s.store_id` assume the `store_id` is in the `stores` table? I'm assuming yes. If so, does it mess anything up if I change it to `r.store_id`? Because that is the table relationship identifier between the two tables.

Comment: This column needs to be in _both_ tables, that's how it connects them.

Comment: You didn't post your table schemas, so I had to make up names for the columns. You'll of course have to translate them to your actual column names.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43896/discussion-between-michael-falciglia-and-barmar)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to spend all night trying to teach you SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through the results if I am understanding the issue correctly. Also, in your MySQL command you need to set an `AS` for the `AVG(rating)`. And I have set `mysql_fetch_assoc` (instead of `mysql_fetch_row`) for the results to be returned in an associative array:

```
foreach ($storeids as $storeid) {
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(rating) AS rating FROM reviews GROUP BY store_id WHERE store_id = '$storeid'");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['rating'];
  }
}
```

**EDIT** Looking at your query and seeing the `$storeid` being set, unclear where that value is coming from but I wrapped the solution I have provided in a `foreach` loop which assumes you have a list—and hopefully an array—that contains all of the `$storeids` in to loop through.

Comment: There's only one result in that query, because of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I'm looking at it, need a few minutes to understand it, a novice here

Comment: The reason I set the store id is because there are 2 tables, maybe I should have put that in the question. One is a table for the store information and one is for reviews on each store. The loop currently is printing data from the store table, the relationship is defined by the store ID

Comment: Thanks Jake, I will experiment some here